# doing research/project on spacetime curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, general-relativity

So I recently undertook the daunting task of presenting a project on general relativity for a differential geometry course.

Does anyone have any suggestions for topic or topics to narrow it down to?

I have about a month and a half to work on this.

Reading material suggestions would also be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have heard that without Riemannian geometry one can not present theory of relativity well.So perhaps start at that

Comment: What is the level of the class? i.e. how much differential geometry do you know?

Comment: beginning graduate level, we've learned up to curves and surfaces (local)

Answer (score 3):

Semi-Riemannian geometry : with applications to relativity by Barrett O'Neill

The Cauchy Problem in General Relativity by Ringstrom

On the Topology and Future Stability of the Universe by Ringstrom